# change button font size in Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework

do the following change for css but not able to change font size

```
set style 

font-size: 16px;

and also set css class 

.x-btn{
 font:normal 18px tahoma, verdana, helvetica;
}

.x-btn button{
    font:normal 18px arial,tahoma,verdana,helvetica;
    color:#333;
}

.x-btn em {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

help me to change font size in Extjs Button

Comment: Is there any way to change the style through javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.x-btn-default-small .x-btn-inner {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

This works for me in extjs 4.0.2

Comment: can you share your example in witch this code is working and in which Extjs version its working

Comment: what extjs version are you using ?

Comment: Is there any way to change the style through javascript?

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the button's configuration.
For example if you declared

```
{ xtype: 'button', textAlign: 'bottom', iconAlign: 'top' ... }
```

you will have to set css as follow:

```
.x-btn-bottom .x-btn-inner {
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold
}
```

You have to inspect css of your button at runtime for example using firebug. You will see
css class to overwrite